# Php delete element in xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use php to delete an xml element but it doesn't work. I tried some different code but no one works. I would also like to use cookies to get element in the future. Can you suggest me what I have to do ? I'm not expert and for this I'm in difficulty.

Here the code:

```
    <?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("Dati.xml");

$matchingElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName("Matematica");
$totalMatches     = $matchingElements->length;

$elementsToDelete = array();

    $elementsToDelete[] = $matchingElements->item(0);

foreach ( $elementsToDelete as $elementToDelete ) {
    $elementToDelete->parentNode->removeChild($elementToDelete);
}

$dom->save($xmlFileToLoad);
echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
   echo "window.close();";
   echo "</script>";
echo "Puoi chiudere questa pagina";

?>
```

Here the xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<Informatica>
<nome>aaaa</nome>
<classe>3C</classe>
<titolo>Informatica</titolo>
<materia>Informatica</materia>
<ISBN>123456789101112</ISBN>
<prezzo>12</prezzo>
<autori>tizio</autori>
<contatto>nanni-lombardo1@hotmail.it</contatto>
<codice>123456</codice>
</Informatica>
<Matematica>
<nome>bbb</nome>
<classe>3C</classe>
<titolo>math</titolo>
<materia>Matematica</materia>
<ISBN>123456789101112</ISBN>
<prezzo>12</prezzo>
<autori>tizio</autori>
<contatto>nanni-lombardo1@hotmail.it</contatto>
<codice>123456</codice>
</Matematica>

</document>
```

Comment: is your var $xmlFileToLoad defined somewhere ? Also, you have a space before "<?xml>", you should remove it.

Comment: Yes I forgot I used cookies

Comment: *btw* You can use `$elementsToDelete = iterator_to_array($matchingElements);` to convert the live node list into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be sure to :

- Remove the space before your XML start tag
- Define your $xmlFileToLoad variable
- Make your destination XML writable ([see Chmod & permissions](https://isabelcastillo.com/linux-chmod-permissions-cheat-sheet))

My test file works fine : https://eu.andredasilva.fr/testandre/test.php (source code : https://eu.andredasilva.fr/testandre/test.php.source)

> Base XML : https://eu.andredasilva.fr/testandre/Dati.xml
>
> Result XML : https://eu.andredasilva.fr/testandre/test.xml

Comment: If it helps, don't forget to mark your problem as solved or upvote, it was a pleasure and a nice case, that I'll reuse soon :) Have a nice day